# Netty channelAcquired is not getting called

Tags: java, events, netty

I'm using netty channel pool for a http client and in the `ChannelPoolHandler` implementation `channelAcquired` is not getting called when the `channelPool.acquire()` invoked. I'm using netty `4.0.32.Final`. Here's how I created the chanelpool. I just followed the simple example listed at netty.io. If someone can just explain what I've done wrong or if there is a bug that'll be very helpful. Thanks.

```
EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
final Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
b.group(group).channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
AbstractChannelPoolMap<InetSocketAddress, SimpleChannelPool> poolMap = new AbstractChannelPoolMap<InetSocketAddress, SimpleChannelPool>() {
    @Override
    protected SimpleChannelPool newPool(InetSocketAddress key) {
        return new SimpleChannelPool(b.remoteAddress(key), new HttpClientPoolHandler());
    }
};

final SimpleChannelPool simpleChannelPool = poolMap.get(new InetSocketAddress(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort()));
final Future<Channel> acquire = simpleChannelPool.acquire();

acquire.addListener(new FutureListener<Channel>() {
    public void operationComplete(Future<Channel> f) throws Exception {
        if (f.isSuccess()) {
            final Channel ch = f.getNow();
            // Send the HTTP request.
            ChannelFuture channelFuture = ch.writeAndFlush(request);
            channelFuture.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture channelFuture) throws Exception {
                    if (channelFuture.isSuccess()) {
                        simpleChannelPool.release(ch);
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            System.out.println("ERROR : " + f.cause());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Looking at the netty source I found out that the `channelAcquired` method is only get called when there is a previously released channel in the pool. else a new channel created without invoking `channelAcquired` method. Is this the way it supposed to be.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `channelAcquired`method will only be called if you "acquire" a previous created channel. In your case there is not channel yet in the pool so it will call `channelCreated`.